# Error on Close Form when open Query in Thread (Delphi)

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have a `Query` and open it in my `Thread`. It works correctly and I don't want to use `Synchronize`, because `Synchronize` makes main `Form` don't response while the `Query` not complete fetch.
When close the `Form` blow error shown:

System Error.  Code: 1400. Invalid window handle

```
type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  public
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure doProc;
  end; { type }
.
.
.
procedure TMyThread.doProc;
begin
  Form1.Query1.Open;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;

  doProc;
end;
.
.
.
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  thrd := TMyThread.Create(True);
  thrd.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  thrd.Resume;
end;
```

Note : `Query` has a lot of record.

Comment: Don't put the query on the form. Make it a local to Execute. Keep it isolated from the minute thread.

Comment: Your thread is due to its `FreeOnTerminate` concept like a thrown paper plane. You should take control of it. Besides, access of the `Query1` object of your form might be unsafe and is most probably cause of your problem. And finally, if it's a `TQuery` object, then you are using an outdated BDE which you could upgrade to something more recent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the VCL is **not** thread safe.
In order to have the query execute in parallel to all other things going on you'll have to decouple it from the Form.

That means you'll have to create the Query at runtime using code:

```
type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FQuery: TQuery;
    FOnTerminate: TNotifyEvent;
  public
    constructor Create(AQuery: TQuery);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure doProc;
    //Add an event handler to do cleanup on termination.
    property OnTerminate: TNotifyEvent read FOnTerminate write FOnTerminate;
  end; { type }

constructor TMyThread.Create(AQuery: TQuery);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FQuery:= AQuery;
end;

procedure TMyThread.doProc;
begin
  FQuery1.Open;
  Synchronize(
    //anonymous method, use a separate procedure in older Delphi versions
    procedure
    begin
      Form1.Button1.Enabled:= true;  //reenable the button when we're done.
    end
  );
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  doProc;
end;

destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnterminate) then FOnTerminate(Self);
  inherited;
end;
```

In the `OnClick` for Button1 you'll do the following:

```
type 
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    AQuery: TQuery;
    ...
  end; {type}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1.Enabled:= false;  //disable the button so it cannot be started twice.
  thrd.Free;
  AQuery:= TQuery.Create;
  AQuery.SQL.Text:= .....
  thrd := TMyThread.Create(AQuery);
  thrd.OnTerminate:= MyTerminationHandler;
  thrd.FreeOnTerminate:= False;
  thrd.Resume;
end;
```

Finally assign cleanup code to the termination handler of the thread. 
If you destroy the Query in the thread then you cannot use `FreeOnTerminate:= true`, but you'll have to Free the thread yourself.

```
procedure TForm1.MyTerminationHandler(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(AQuery);
end;
```

**Warning**
This code will only work if you start 1 thread.
If you want start this thread multiple times (i.e. run multiple queries at the same time), you'll have to create an array of threads e.g.:

```
TQueryThreads = record
  MyThread: TMyThread;
  MyQuery: TQuery;
  constructor Create(SQL: string);
end; {record}

TForm1 = class(TForm)
private
  Threads: array of TQueryThreads;
 ....
end; {TForm1}
```

**Note that this code will not work in the BDE, because that library does not support multiple running queries at the same time**
If you want to do that you'll have to use ZEOS or something like that.

As per TLama's suggestion:
I would suggest switching the BDE TQuery component to ADO, or downloading something like [ZEOS components](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib/). The BDE is very outdated and has a lot of quirks that will never get fixed because it is no longer maintained.

The only issue that remains is cleaning up the connection if `Form1` is closed.
If it's your main form it really does not matter because your whole application will go down.
If it's not your main form than you'll need to disable closing the form by filling the `OnCanClose` handler.

```
TForm1.CanClose(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: boolean);
begin
  CanClose:= thrd.Finished;
end;
```

Comment: Closing the form while the tread is running causes trouble, starting a new MyThread is causing trouble (you must not use a connection at the same time from concurrent threads). This has many unwanted side effects

Comment: @SirRufo, that's why I disabled `Button1`, so you cannot start the same action twice. This will not prevent you from initiation another query, which the BDE will not like.  I've added a suggestion to utilize another database library that **does** support multiple running queries.

Comment: Yes, you have to write a lot of code just to prevent side effects (disable all actions, closing form) or simply use a modal form and be fine. Both will work but I like the lazy programmers way to keep things simple and maintainable

Comment: BTW: The OP want to open a dataset, but your example frees the query instance on thread termination. How should he access the query results?

Comment: I was too busy cleaning up....:-) He'd access the result right before killing the Query, either in `doProc` or in the `destructor`. Another option is to free the Query in the ButtonClick, right before it gets reconstructed.

Answer (score 1):

You should prevent any action (user and program) in the MainThread without blocking it. This can easily be done by a modal form, that cannot be closed by the user.

The thread can do anything as long as it takes and the final (synchronized) step is to close that modal form.

```
procedure OpenDataSetInBackground( ADataSet : TDataSet );
var
  LWaitForm : TForm;
begin
  LWaitForm := TForm.Create( nil );
  try
    LWaitForm.BorderIcons := []; // no close buttons

    TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
      procedure
      begin
        try
          ADataSet.Open;
        finally
          TThread.Synchronize( nil, 
            procedure
            begin
              LWaitForm.Close;
            end );
        end;
      end );
    try
      LWaitForm.ShowModal;
    finally
      LWorkThread.Free;
    end;
  finally
    LWaitForm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

But you have to be careful with this and you should never try do start more than one parallel thread with this code unless you really know, what you are doing.

Comment: Why open a modal form and then create a separate thread. It makes no sense, You might as well block all action and forget about the thread.

Comment: Because to avoid an unresponding application? That is the main point of this question.

Comment: The modal dialog will be just as bad as an unresponding application. It makes me wait for the machine, which is bad UI design. The machine must wait for me, not the other way round. If I'm going to flash a modal dialog, I might as well dispense with the thread and disable all buttons and borders on a `please wait, I'm in stupid mode` modal dialog. It will be easier to program.